# Managing dependencies with spring boot profiles and Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot

I created a java project that will use spring boot and Gradle. I would like to configure profiles, for the different environment (development on my local machine, systemtest for integration test on server farm machine etc). I would use h2 in memory database for development environment and SqlServer for systemtest environment. In build.gradle I defined the following dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2:1.4.195')
    runtime('com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc')
}
```

I created a application.yml file, application-development.yml and application-systemtest.yml where I would put common properties and environment specific properties. The file application-systemtest.yml defines the connecction parameters for sql server

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://<host>,1433;databaseName=MYDB
    username: myuser
    password: mypass
    driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

I would also create an uber-jar and select the profile as a launch parameter, ie

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=systemtest -jar <my uber jar>
```

The development profiles starts fine and I am running on h2 in memory database. When trying systemtest profile, spring boot fails to load contexts and fails. This is caused by spring boot finding h2 dependency and trying to configure datasource defined in application-systemtest.yml

So I modified the build.gradle dependencies closure

```
def profile = project.findProperty('spring.profiles.active')

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    if (profile == 'development') {
        runtime('com.h2database:h2:1.4.195')
    } else {
        runtime('com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc')
    }
}
```

This time spring boot start correctly. Don't like very much this solution as I have to handle the profile configuration partly with Gradle. I would like to know if there is a way to configure spring boot so that profile is completely managed within itself, resolving h2 in development environment and sqlserver in systemtest environment, leaving Gradle unaware of spring profiles.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: explicitly specify `spring.datasource.type` for your `systemtest` profile for the datasource implementation you are using. That way datasource detection is skipped (embedded has precedence when detection is going on).

Comment: I tried to look at Spring documentation but was unable find which value I may assign to spring.datasource.type. Docs are rather vague. I tried to set a Datasource class but it wasn't working.

Comment: You should set a datasource class... Something like `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be advisable to have a different artifact / binary depending on the DB product. Try to configure the datasources / Spring profiles as suggested by @M. Deinum to prevent the datasource to be configured as H2 when using a different DB.